# Сортировка структур в бинарном файле

Tags: c, файлы

Подскажите, как отсортировать структуры в бинарном файле не используя буфер.

Comment: В смысле, читая их по одной и не храня в памяти, или что?

Comment: Не совсем, у меня есть одна перемененная в которой хранится новая запись, и вторая переменная которую записываем структуру

Comment: я понимаю что надо использовать fseek

Comment: Ну то есть за O(1) пространства, как ни крути.

Comment: Суть задания добавить новую структуру не нарушив упорядоченности(они отсортированы лексикографически). Сложность возникла в том как сместить все остальные записи после того как я добавил новую

Comment: 1. Прочитать самую последнюю. 2. Записать ее в конец файла, сразу после ее текущего адреса. 3. Перейти к предыдущей, далее везде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну да, fseek, чтобы можно было читать и писать по произвольному адресу.

По идее, сгодится любой in-place-алгоритм (bubble sort, insertion sort, даже quicksort или heapsort можно 0_o), только вместо ОЗУ структуры хранятся в файле.

Например, insertion.

1. Читаем текущую структуру по адресу n (то есть начиная с байта `n * sizeof(Struct)`, n >= 0).
2. Сдвигаем file pointer на размер сруктуры влево и читаем предыдущую, по адресу n - 1. Если она не больше текущей, оставляем все как есть. Если больше — записываем по адресу n и сдвигаемся вправо, на адрес n - 2. Когда мы дошли до структуры по адресу k - 1, которая не больше текущей, записываем текущую по адресу k.
3. Повторить для следующей, по адресу n + 1, и далее, пока файл не кончится.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую реализовать

Comment: Получилось, спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Пожалуйста. :-)